# Fail to "blink"/ change color of tkinter widget when using `after`

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to simulate a blink of a label widget by changing its color in this manner:

a) change to color #1, pause 1 sec,

b) change to color #2, pause 1 sec,

c) loop again using `tk.after` to rerun this procedure.

But the result is a constant color, #2.

`self.blink_status` is an index telling communication status is OK, and equals to `1`. of course code was tested with a constant value `self.blink_status=1`

```
def blink_tx(self):
    if self.blink_status == 1:
        self.tx_label["bg"] = 'green'
        self.tx_value.set('Tx')
        sleep(1)
        self.tx_label["bg"] = 'blue'
        sleep(1)
    elif self.blink_status == 0:
        self.tx_label["bg"] = 'red'
        self.tx_value.set('*')
        sleep(2)
        self.tx_label["bg"] = 'orange'
    else:
        self.tx_label["bg"] = 'red'
        self.tx_value.set('x')
        sleep(2)

    self.status_frame.after(3500, self.blink_tx)
```

the way `self.tx_label` and `self.tx_value` are defined :

```
self.tx_label = tk.Label(self.status_frame, textvariable=self.tx_value, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=2)
self.tx_label.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=tk.E)
```

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque - I'm trying to bring only relevant code, regarding blink itself, I'll update to be more understandable

Comment: Well you are using sleep in your code. This by itself will cause your application to freeze and not work as expected.

Comment: @Mike-SMT that is why i'm using `after` which allow code to continue running regardless `sleep`.

Comment: No. That's not what happening. Remove `sleep()` completely from your code. You will need to create a new function to call using the `after()` method inside of `blink_tx`. You cannot use `sleep()` ever inside of a tkinter instance. You can use it in a separate thread outside of a tkinter isntance but not within.

Comment: @Mike-SMT what will create the delay effect between the 2 colors?

Comment: @Guy.D: no, `after` doesn't "allow code to continue running regardless of sleep". You need to use `after` _instead_ of sleep.

Comment: @BryanOakley- thank you. I thought it was some kind of thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `sleep()` inside of a tkinter instance. Tkinter is a single thread application and when you tell it to sleep everything in the event list is put on hold/freezes. You need to use `after()`for any delays in your code. The `after()` method is specifically meant to manage delays in tkinter.

Because in your example it appears you are running 2 separate delays my example will provide both delays.

Here is an exampled composed from the code you provided.
We can set all the delays we need buy provided a 2nd function. I have added a random number generator to the code to illustrate a continuous change of the colors.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.tx_value = tk.StringVar()
        self.tx_value.set("test")
        self.blink_status = 1

        self.tx_label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.tx_value, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=4, height=2)
        self.tx_label.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=tk.E)
        self.blink_tx()

    def blink_tx_step_2(self, color=None):
        if color != None:
            self.tx_label["bg"] = color
        self.after(3500, self.blink_tx)

    def blink_tx(self):
        if self.blink_status == 1:
            self.tx_label["bg"] = 'green'
            self.tx_value.set('Tx')
            self.blink_status = random.randint(0, 2)
            self.after(1000, self.blink_tx_step_2, 'blue')
        elif self.blink_status == 0:
            self.tx_label["bg"] = 'red'
            self.tx_value.set('*')
            self.blink_status = random.randint(0, 2)
            self.after(2000, self.blink_tx_step_2, 'orange')
        else:
            self.tx_label["bg"] = 'red'
            self.tx_value.set('x')
            self.blink_status = random.randint(0, 2)
            self.after(2000, self.blink_tx_step_2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: great- I didn't think entering several `after` is allowed. silly me :)

Comment: @Guy.D the `after()` method only adds an command to the event list and will tell tkinter to not execute said command until a set amount of time has passed. It will not guarantee this will go of in exactly the time you mention but it will guarantee it will not go off before the time mentioned.

Comment: you both are :)

Answer (score 3):

`time.sleep()` is blocking your GUI updates; do not use it with a GUI. Use `root.after` instead.

The following label will start blinking when you click on the GUI:
You can adapt it to your own code that was not provided.

```
import tkinter as tk


class BlinkerLabel(tk.Label):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.status = 1

    def blink(self, event):
        if self.status == 1:
            self["bg"] = 'green'
        elif self.status == 0:
            self["bg"] = 'red'

        self.status = (self.status + 1) % 2
        self.after(3500, self.blink, 'dummy_event')  # <-- this creates the 'delay' between blinks


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    lbl = BlinkerLabel(root, text='I blink!')
    lbl.pack()

    root.bind('<Button-1>', lbl.blink)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you. As far as I understand an event of button press will cause the blink, how can It be done contantly without the need to press ( it use is an indication "bulb" in a GUI )

Comment: No, this BlinkerLabel will blink constantly, every 3500 milliseconds.

Comment: Oh. now i understand the modulus part

Comment: Yes, the modulus is to toggle from `status=0` to `status=1`

Comment: it seems as a mathematician way to solve using modulus - LIKE!, but in my case `self.status`  is a result of `ping` test which yields `1`. meaning that every time cycle its value can be `0`,`1`,`NULL`. how can I use the modulus that way ?

Comment: Do you want the color to change depending on the value of some parameter that you would provide to the label?

Comment: Yes. That’s what I meant

Comment: I see... then it is a lot easier than a blinker: you create a callback linked to your event: `ping` at interval using `root.after`, then, depending on the result returned by the ping, update the aspect of the label. I have to go, so I probably won't be able to help you right now, but maybe @Mike-SMT will like to help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Mike-SMT and  @Reblochon Masque for helping. **TNX ALOT**

My code fix:

```
def blink_tx(self):
    def blink_1(color1, color2, txt):
        self.tx_label["bg"] = color1
        self.tx_value.set(txt)
        self.after(t_blink, blink_2, color2)

    def blink_2(color):
        self.tx_label["bg"] = color
        self.after(t_blink, self.blink_tx)

    t_blink = 2500
    if self.blink_status == 1:
        blink_1('green', 'orange', 'Tx')
    elif self.blink_status == 0:
        blink_1('red', 'yellow', '*')
    else:
        blink_1('red', 'red', 'X')
```